# how to use python-mysqldb with python 2.7.9 in ubuntu

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

I installed Python 2.7.9 and make it global on my ubuntu by pyenv.
Then I installed mysql and mysqldb. I input `import MySQLdb`, which shows that `No module named MySQLdb`.
When I change Python version to the system version(2.7.6), I can import the MySQLdb module.
What's the reason?
How can we use mysql with changed Python version?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you install mysqldb ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`

Comment: Then it's likely that the mysqldb has followed the same path as the official python installation (2.7.6) and has been installed in that version.
I think you should try to install mysqldb using pip or easy_install making sure you run pip with python 2.7.9

Comment: Thank you,i can use it by `pip install MySQL-python`